# How insert to file one column from table in python

Tags: python, pandas, file, copy

I want to copy and write from one file to another a new one column.
I have a file:

```
1 12 13 14
2 22 23 24
3 32 33 34
4 42 43 44
5 52 53 54
6 62 63 64
```

I need to copy 4 column to new file.

In the code, you can see that I take the file and delete the first two lines in it. After that, my attempts to create a file with one column.

```
f=open("1234.txt").readlines()
for i in [0,0,-1]:
    f.pop(i)
with open("1234.txt",'w') as F:
    F.writelines(f)
ff = open("1234.txt", 'r')
df1 = ff.iloc[:,3:3]
print(df1)

with open('12345.txt', 'w') as F:
    df.writelines('12345.txt')
```

I’m not sure whether to import something for iloc, may be it pandas? Should I close files in code and when?

Comment: yes in pandas you can do `df[1:]` to de-consider the first 2 lines. and then `df[1:].to_csv('\path\file.txt',sep='\t')` will give you a tab delimited file without first 2 lines

Comment: With deleting first 2 lines are not problem. What about 4 column?

Comment: if you dont want the last column: `df.iloc[:,:-1]` should work